# Authentications methods in Rails: web client and mobile client

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, authentication

In rails i want write an authentication system from scratch.
This authentication must works for web clients and mobile apps.

There are any tutorials that explain how to achieve that?
I know that for web clients i can use this http://railscasts.com/episodes/250-authentication-from-scratch and for mobile apps i must use json + token authentication.
But how i must integrate the two form of authentication in one controller?

Thanks